# How to restore accidentally truncate mysql table

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have accidentally truncate mysql table table1. The truncated data are very very important. I used wampserver latest version. Unfortunately I do not have binary logs. I have wamp folder under drive C in Windows 10. Now I am trying to restore the database folder using Windows data recovery tool. Is there any other possibilities to restore my truncated table?

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60722/how-to-recover-truncate-table-in-mysql) for the answer. Hope this helps.

If you have binary logging enabled, you can replay changes that went into creating the stats table, up to the point where you did the TRUNCATE.

But you may not have binary logs for all changes to that table from the beginning of time. It's common to have binary logs only back a few days. Any data that was created in that table prior to your oldest binary log is not recoverable.